# Mirrors in yum cache

Tags: linux

I am trying to find all mirrors inside a yum cache. But I don't understand what kind of files these mirrors actually are.

I resolved my problem in this way:

```
find /var/cache/yum -type f -name "*"
```

But I am not sure about my conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all the enabled repositories on your system with :

```
yum repolist enabled
```

If you need more verbosity add `-v` parameter :

```
yum -v repolist enabled
```

Comment: Ok!I have seen the list using your last command. What files are mirrors?All of them?

Comment: As I have understood surfing the internet these files are something like:               http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release